# How to code for measuring the blood glucose level using NEAR INFRA RED SENSOR

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, sensor

I want to know how to code NEAR INFRA RED SENSOR to measure the blood glucose level using Arduino or NodeMCU. I searched about this topic in the internet. I have only found lots of pdf with the Instruction. No one has the code for measuring blood glucose level. Does anybody here have the code for measuring the blood glucose level using NEAR INFRA RED SENSOR?

Comment: Which "NEAR INFRA RED SENSOR"?

Comment: *if anybody have the code* NO, we don't have "the code". And if you think having "the code" solves all your problems then you still have **a lot** to learn. "Code" describes a certain **behavior**, once you have clear what the behavior should be, writing software ("the code") should not be too hard. Knowing "the code" that was used to put a man on the moon is only a small part of the whole project. You still need a spacesuit and a rocketship.

Comment: @Sharifdeen - This is a very complex subject. You may find some guidelines in [these existing questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=glucose) . It would be useful if you could improve your question so it is suitable for reopening - what sensors are you considering?, can you provide some links that you have found and can you explain why you cannot write code to implement what you have found? Help us help you.

Comment: Sharifdeen The link provided by JRE [here](https://www.ijltet.org/journal/151486536919.%2065.pdf) shows a sensor and associated circuitry that can be used and provides numerical results. The hardware in the sensor section is low cost and relatively simple. No code is given but they show flowcharts of the processes and the use of an Arduino to provide a Bluetooth link to a cellphone. If you are unable to convert the information provided here into working Arduino code then you do not have enough experience to tackle this project.

Answer (score 3):

[This explains it clearly enough, and includes the needed hardware.](https://www.ijltet.org/journal/151486536919.%2065.pdf)

> The  inbuilt ADC  block  is  used  for  converting  the  received  analog  signal  to  digital  form.  This  digital  signal  is  processed  by  using  second order  regression  analysis  to  predict  the  blood  glucose  value  and  the  blood  glucose  value  is  displayed  on  the  LCD  display.

The coefficients needed to convert the measured voltage to the glucose levels would be part of your research - you wil have to make lots of measurements using a standard method and in parallel make measurements with your near infrared (NIR) setup.  You would then do some curve fitting to figure out how to "warp" your voltages into glucose values.

---

I suspect the measured voltage will have some dependance on the color and thickness of the skin as well as the "brightness" of the NIR.  There will probably also be some influence from light (visible and infrared) from the environment.

The one I've linked to will be particularly bad about the "brightness" of the NIR.  It uses the unregulated voltage from a 9V battery to power the LED. As the battery voltage drops during discharge, the NIR LED "brightness" will drop.

Comment: Works OK in final form. Interesting paper. Good enough results for real world use.